# Undefined symbol in TASM

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

[image]

```
.model small
.code
org 100h
s:
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 47
int 21h
mov dl, 55
int 21h
mov dl, 5A
int 21h
mov dl, 4D
int 21h
mov dl, 41
int 21h
mov dl, 4E
int 21h
mov dl, 41
int 21h
mov dl, 2C
int 21h
mov dl, 20
int 21h
mov dl, 49
int 21h
mov dl, 53
int 21h
mov dl, 48
int 21h
mov dl, 52
int 21h
mov dl, 41
int 21h
mov dl, 45
int 21h
mov dl, 4C
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, ‘I’
int 21h
mov dl, ’S’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘H’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘R’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘A’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘E’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘L’
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, ‘G’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘U’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘Z’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘M’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘A’
int 21h
mov dl, ’N’
int 21h
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl, ‘M’
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, ’N’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘A’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘L’
int 21h
mov dl, ‘O’
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, 'P'
int 21h
mov dl, '.'
int 21h
mov dl, 'C'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, 'M'
int 21h
mov dl, 'P'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, 'S'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, 'M'
int 21h
mov dl, 'P'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, 'L'
int 21h
mov dl, 'O'
int 21h
mov dl, 'C'
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, 'M'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, 'N'
int 21h
mov dl, 'I'
int 21h
mov dl, 'L'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl, 'B'
int 21h
mov dl, 'S'
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, 'I'
int 21h
mov dl, 'T'
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, 'D'
int 21h
mov dl, 'I'
int 21h
mov dl, 'G'
int 21h
mov dl, 'I'
int 21h
mov dl, 'T'
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, 'L'
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
mov dl, 'R'
int 21h
mov dl, 'T'
int 21h
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl, 'J'
int 21h
mov dl, 'U'
int 21h
mov dl, 'N'
int 21h
mov dl, 'E'
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, '8'
int 21h
mov dl, ','
int 21h
mov dl, ' '
int 21h
mov dl, '1'
int 21h
mov dl, '9'
int 21h
mov dl, '9'
int 21h
mov dl, '6'
int 21h
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl, '0'
int 21h
mov dl, '9'
int 21h
mov dl, '7'
int 21h
mov dl, '7'
int 21h
mov dl, '4'
int 21h
mov dl, '6'
int 21h
mov dl, '5'
int 21h
mov dl, '3'
int 21h
mov dl, '6'
int 21h
mov dl, '6'
int 21h
mov dl, '9'
int 21h
mov dl,10
int 21h
mov dl, 'm'
int 21h
mov dl, 'a'
int 21h
mov dl, 'c'
int 21h
mov dl, 'h'
int 21h
mov dl, 'i'
int 21h
mov dl, 'k'
int 21h
mov dl, 'o'
int 21h
mov dl, 'j'
int 21h
mov dl, 'a'
int 21h
mov dl, 'v'
int 21h
mov dl, 'i'
int 21h
mov dl, 'e'
int 21h
mov dl, 'r'
int 21h
mov dl, '@'
int 21h
mov dl, 'g'
int 21h
mov dl, 'm'
int 21h
mov dl, 'a'
int 21h
mov dl, 'i'
int 21h
mov dl, 'l'
int 21h
mov dl, '.'
int 21h
mov dl, 'c'
int 21h
mov dl, 'o'
int 21h
mov dl, 'm'
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end s
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify your question. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking further. question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `org 100h` is only needed for `.com` programs (`.model tiny`). Remove it for `.exe` programs (`.model small`).

When you feed TASM with a number, the assembler expects by default a **decimal** number. The numbers in your program are **hexadecimal** (5A, 4D...). You can add the character 'h' to each number to signalize that this is a hexadecimal number or you can change the numeral system to hexadecimal numbers with the directive `RADIX 16` at the beginning of the program. Since the suffix system is still present, a value like `4D` will be interpreted as "decimal 4" due to the 'D'. So change that number to `4Dh`.  Don't forget to change the subsequent line feed ASCII values (10) to 0A (hexadecimal) or 10d (with suffix).

A character has to be decorated with quotes (double or single). The sign for the quotes is ' (single) and " (double). For example: `mov dl, 'G'`. Obviously you've copied the source from the web and have got some different unicode quotation marks. You have to change them to the quotation characters you find on your keyboard.